# How to calculate the scale's result?

Tags: math, d3.js

I am new to d3.js library, and I am trying to understand the concept of domain and ranges.

I read [Scott Murray's book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch07.html#_creating_a_scale), but I don't know how to calculate it.

I have this:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([100, 500])
    .range([10, 350]);

scale(100);  //Returns 10
scale(300);  //Returns 180
scale(500);  //Returns 350
```

I know that 100 units of my input represent 10 in my output, and the same with 500 and 350... but why 180 is returned for 300 as input? How can I calculate this value?

I read [this tutorial](https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3js-scales) too, which explains how to calculate it, but when I follow the method, I don't get the same value, i.e., `scale(300)` doesn't return `180`.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I will try to explain why you get 180.

We have that 300 is the value that ideally divide your domain into two subdomains of the same size, so we can do:
`500 - 100 / 2 = 200` (this is the subdomain size),
this implies that the middle value is located at:
`200 + 100 = 300` (note that we add the starting point `100`)

So with the range we do the same:
`350 - 10 / 2 = 170`
and then we add the starting point
`170 + 10 = 180`

Comment: Thanks @Davide Vozzi I undestand but how calculate scale(200) to obtain 95

Comment: Like this: the point 200  is a quarter of the domain (400 / 100 = 4) so for the  range: 350 -10 / 4 = 85 then it becomes 85 + 10 = 95.

Comment: If you wont to make it easy you can translate the domain and the range to the origin so domain becomes [0,400] and range[0,340] then you scale your value (200 becomes 100) and again `400/100=4` then for the range `340/4=85` and at the end add the traslation again `10`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry @Davide Vozzi I don't understand very well... in both case how you obtain 400.. for example in the first case `.domain([100, 500]) .range([10, 350]);` what is the equation ... for example is I try to calculate scale(125) in console this return 31,25... but If I calculate by myself... I obtain other value ...how to obtain the number to device '350-10/x'

Comment: You take the domain intervall (500 -100=400) then you divide it by the domain value scaled by the initial domain piont (125-100=25) so you have `400/25=16` then use this value to divide you range interval values   
`(( 350 - 10 ) / 16) + 10 = 31.25` :)

Answer (score 24):

## THE EQUATION OF THE LINE

To get the equation used in a D3 linear scale you only need to understand that such scale uses a linear interpolation. In simple words, all you need is the *equation of the line* created by the two points you're passing to D3 scale generator.

In your example...

```
.domain([100, 500])
.range([10, 350]);
```

...will give us two points, using the Cartesian coordinates system (x, y):

- The first point is `100,10` (`x = 100` and `y = 10`)
- The second point is `500,350` (`x = 500` and `y = 350`)

Keep in mind that in my explanation the x axis represents what in math is called the domain (in D3 lingo, also *domain*), that is, the set of input values, while the y axis represents what in math is called the image (in D3 lingo, the *range*), that is, the set of output values.

So, using those two points, this is the line you get:

[image]

Now let's explain *visually* what a linear scale like this one does:

Choose any point in the x axis (it can even be outside the domain). This is your **input** value (in the domain). Go up (or down) until you cross the red line. The y coordinate of the point where you cross the red line corresponds to your **output** value (in the image, or range).

Now, back to the equation:

Having our 2 points, we can now calculate the equation of the line.

The general equation of the line is:

[image]

Where *y* (also known as ***f(x)*** in most math books) is the range, and *x* is the domain.

The first step is finding *m*, which we can do using our 4 points:

[image]

Remember that:

- x1 is the first value in the domain array (=100)
- x2 is the last value in the domain array (=500)
- y1 is the first value in the range array (=10)
- y2 is the last value in the range array (=350)

Putting all these four values in the equation, it gives us that *m* is **17/20**.

Now, solving the equation for b (using any of the two points)...

[image]

... we have that b is **-75**, which gives us our final equation:

[image]

And that's it. Using this equation, you can get any point in the image (range), relative to any domain input.

**Example:**

Let's calculate the output (range) for 125 (as in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535370/how-to-calculate-the-range-in-d3-js/40539729#comment68315493_40537174)). Very easy:

[image]

And that gives us... **31.25**!