# Ordinal scale behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to create an ordinal scale with one to one correspondence between range and domain. I would expect that values/strings that do not belong to the domain would return nothing. Instead I get the following behaviour:

```
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(['a', 'b', 'c']).range([10, 20, 30])
x('d')
10
x('e')
20
x('f')
30
```

Is there any logic behind this behaviour? Maybe I am missing something, but I couldn't find something out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour of an ordinal scale. Actually, D3 scales (quantitative or qualitative) are made in such a way that you can pass values outside the domain (see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539729/5768908)).

If you want to define outputs for unknown inputs, use [scale.unknown()](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#ordinal_unknown):

```js
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    .range([10, 20, 30])
    .unknown("not in the scale");

console.log("a is " + x("a"));
console.log("b is " + x("b"));
console.log("c is " + x("c"));
console.log("f is " + x("f"));
console.log("xyz is " + x("xyz"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: Regarding OP's question in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673878/d3-js-v4-ordinal-scale-behaviour/40675350?noredirect=0#comment68581601_40675350):

> Are the range values for values outside the domain chosen randomly or is there a logic?

The logic can be seen inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/src/ordinal.js):

```
function scale(d) {
    var key = d + "", i = index.get(key);
    if (!i) {
        if (unknown !== implicit) return unknown;
        index.set(key, i = domain.push(d));
    }
    return range[(i - 1) % range.length];
}
```

It shows us that, if the value doesn't exist, it's pushed into the domain. So, values not specified in the domain will have an output that will "cycle" through the range. Check this demo, the output is `10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20...`:

```js
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    .range([10, 20, 30]);

console.log("d is " + x("d"));
console.log("e is " + x("e"));
console.log("f is " + x("f"));
console.log("g is " + x("g"));
console.log("h is " + x("h"));
console.log("i is " + x("i"));
console.log("j is " + x("j"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Which has the same outcome of writing this:

```
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'])
.range([10, 20, 30]);
```

In this case `d` corresponds to 10, `e` corresponds to 20, `f` corresponds to 30 etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot! A follow up question: Are the range values for values outside the domain chosen randomly or is there a logic?

Comment: That's a good question in itself, I was wondering the same thing. Because, e.g. if you defined a set of colours for a bar chart, once all colours are use, d3 starts over at the beginning. Thus, I would have expected the values to be d=>10, e=>20, f=>30. Alternatively, if d3 recognizes the alphabetical order, I would have expected d=>40, e=>50, f=>60. But I can't wrap my head around the behaviour described in the question.

Comment: @Paul I edited the question. Apparently there was a bug caused by my browser, printing x('e') equal to 10 instead of 20. The correct behaviour is what Gerardo Furtado describes in his answer. Nevertheless, it is now clear how ordinal scales behave