# D3 Bar Chart Axis quirk

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram, axis

I have this code: https://plnkr.co/edit/t1GKaQOGnFxkTMK03Ynk

```
  var MIN = 60;
  var HR = MIN * 60;
  var tripDomain = [0, 15*MIN, 30*MIN, 45*MIN, 60*MIN, 90*MIN, Math.max(24*HR, d3.max(data))];

  var bins = d3.histogram()
    .thresholds(tripDomain)(data);

  var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(tripDomain)
    .range(tripDomain.map((_,i) => (i/(tripDomain.length-1))*width));

   // ...more code...

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

That renders a histogram correctly. The only issue is that the axis first tick is painting 0 and 61 on top of each other. It should be only 0... not sure where the 61 is coming from (it's the first value of the data) but I don't see how it ended up in the axis.

Notice the first value on the axis... Could you shed some light on this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...not sure where the 61 is coming from.

It's coming from the scale's domain, which you are changing when you append the rectangles and the texts! And that's the expected behaviour, since you're using an ordinal scale.

#### Explanation:

Your x scale domain is well defined:

```
[0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 5400, 1280703]
```

However, in your first bin, you have this (as array properties):

```
[x0: 61, x1: 900]
```

So, whenever you use the `x0` of the first bin with the x scale, for instance:

```
.attr("transform", function(d){
    return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; 
});
```

...you're actually **introducing** a new value in the domain (for a detailed explanation, see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673878/ordinal-scale-behaviour/40675350#40675350)), since there is no `61` in the x scale domain.

By the way, this new value is introduced at the **end** of the domain and, despite being very close to `0`, that `61` is actually the last tick.

#### Solution:

Declare the `unknown`:

```
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .unknown(0)
```

Here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/n1IoEkHcL0sGUraDVCfc?p=preview

Comment: thank you for your thorough answer and updated plunker! It was very useful. I got a better understanding about the scales