# Ordinal scale does not color in properly despite unknown being implied?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am attempting to make a monitoring interface that checks Windows services and determines its state and start_type using `var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()`.

If the state is "RUNNING", I want to color in the cell green. If the state is "STOPPED", I want to color in the cell red. Any other values, to color in white.

Here is my full code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var parsedCSV = d3.csv("servicecheckupreport.csv", function(parsedCSV){



    var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain([" ","RUNNING","STOPPED"])
        .range(["White","MediumSpringGreen","OrangeRed"]);

    var body = d3.select("body");
    var headers = Object.keys(parsedCSV[0]);

    var table = body.append('table')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody');

    var head = thead.selectAll('th')
        .data(headers)
        .enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(parsedCSV)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) {
            return Object.values(d);
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .style("background-color", function(d) {
          if(d){
            return colorScale(d);
            }else{
              return "White";
              }
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });
        }); 
</script>
```

This is the output:

[image]

The problem is, the code will color in the ip address and hostname when those cells should be white.

I am attempting to invoke `ordinal.unknown()` by using a third value in my array as listed below:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([" ","RUNNING","STOPPED"])
    .range(["White","MediumSpringGreen","OrangeRed"]);
```

The first value of the array `" "` indicates any values that are outside of the second and third on the array will be colored in white, yet it still doesn't.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but why are you loading both versions 3 and 4 of `d3`?

Answer (score 1):

`unknown` is only available in D3 v4.x, and you have to set it **explicitly**:

```js
var data = ["RUNNING", "foo", "STOPPED", "RUNNING", "bar", "STOPPED"];

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["RUNNING","STOPPED"])
    .unknown("White")
    .range(["MediumSpringGreen","OrangeRed"]);
    
data.forEach(function(d){ console.log(colorScale(d))});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

A v3 alternative is calling `colorScale` only for the two defined values:

```js
var data = ["RUNNING", "foo", "STOPPED", "RUNNING", "bar", "STOPPED"];

var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["RUNNING","STOPPED"])
    .range(["MediumSpringGreen","OrangeRed"]);
        
data.forEach(function(d){ 
    if(d === "RUNNING" || d === "STOPPED"){
        console.log("White");
    } else {
    console.log(colorScale(d));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Besides that, what you said...

> The first value of the array " " indicates any values that are outside of the second and third on the array will be colored in white.

... is not correct. A space is not a wildcard for any other value.

And, to finish, I don't know your data structure, but it seems to me that no value is matching (for instance, "STATE: 4 RUNNING" is different from "RUNNING"), and the scale is just cycling through the range. To read more about this, have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40675350/5768908