# Understanding D3 domain and ranges

Tags: d3.js

I have a temperature range of 33 degrees to 64 degrees F. I'm trying to figure out the pixel position of 59 degrees along a y-axis that spans 600 pixels. This is for a column chart.

Full disclosure, this is homework that I've been grappling for a while and simply have not yet figured it out.

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([33,64]).range([0,64]);
```

scale(59) returns 53.677419354838705 which is the wrong answer.
600 - 53.677419354838705 is also the wrong answer.

What might I be missing?

Thank you.

Comment: can u  try range([0,600])

Comment: As the comment above says, your range is incorrect. If you want a mathematical explanation of how a linear scale works, have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535370/how-to-calculate-the-range-in-d3-js/40539729#40539729

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The **domain** is the complete set of values, so in this case that is all of your temperatures, from 33 to 64. The **range** is the set of resulting values of a function, in this case the resulting values of scaling your temperatures from 0 to 600.

So you're almost there, you're just using the wrong range - in this case your range should be the span of your y-axis (0 - 600):

`var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([33, 64]).range([0, 600]);`

Which will result in `scale(59)` giving an output of `503.2258064516129`.

Comment: I tried 503.2258064516129 and I still get the wrong answer. I also tried subtracting it from 600 and still get the wrong answer. The height of the bar for 59 degrees should should correspond to a pixel length but the y axis start at 0 and increases downward. Thats why I try subtracting from 600. I even tried rounding to an integer.

Comment: @martinbshp Why are you saying "I get the wrong answer"? What's the *correct answer*? Le Fleur's answer is correct given the problem you described.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado OP never said, that the temperature range should fit the entire axis' range. My guess would be either *553.125* (`.domain([0,64]).range([0,600])`), or probably even *506.25* (`.domain([32,64]).range([0,600])`). This is one of the questions dealing with an artificial problem, where you just cannot win due to a lack of information. This absorbs so much energy and attention to a degree, which real makes me sad.

Comment: @altocumulus, you are so correct.  This tag is getting worse and worse lately.  Now that Matt has fixed the scale problem, the OP's question has shifted to how to draw a bar chart...

Comment: Well, if he/she never said that the temperature fit the entire axis, only a clairvoyant can answer this one...