# Linear scale inconsistency between x/y and width/height

Tags: d3.js, svg, scale

I am using d3 to make a bar graph, and I am running into an issue where the x values in a `rect` element seem to behave differently than the width values, same applies to y and height values. The strange thing is that I am passing the same values to the each counterpart.

I am testing out this issue and getting strange results, shown below with an image. Note that the yScale is being inverted when setting the range. My expectation is that the rectangle's four corners should touch the four circles, but that is not the case. Any reason for this behavior?

Image:

[image: Image of results]

My code:

```
const xMax = dataset.length-1;
const yMax = d3.max(dataset, (d)=> d[1]);

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain([0, xMax])
                 .range([padding, width-padding]);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain([0, yMax])
                 .range([height-padding,padding]);


svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(0))
  .attr('cy', yScale(0))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('cy', yScale(0))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('cy', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(0))
  .attr('cy', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('rect')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('x', xScale(0))
  .attr('y', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('width', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('height', yScale(yMax));
```

Comment: *"The strange thing is that I am passing the same values to the each counterpart."*. No, you're not: you're passing `xScale(0)` to the `x` position, and `xScale(xMax)` to the width. Nothing wrong or inconsistent here. If you want the rectangle going to the 4 circles, it has to be: `.attr('x', xScale(0)).attr('y', yScale(yMax)).attr('width', xScale(xMax) - padding).attr('height', yScale(0) - padding);`

Comment: Or, more idiomatic: `.attr('x', xScale(0)).attr('y', yScale(yMax)).attr('width', xScale(xMax) - xScale(0)).attr('height', yScale(0) - yScale(yMax));`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I see, thanks for your answer and sorry I misworded it. It works now, but I still don't understand why subtracting the padding is necessary. Why doesn't setting the range from `padding` to `width - padding` make xScale(xMax) the same value as `width - padding`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Actually, you know what. I think I understand now. Thanks :)

Comment: Good, do you see that the rectangle's right-hand end doesn't correspond to the circle `x` position? You have to subtract the rectangle's x position to get that. I wrote you a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the rectangle doesn't go to the four points (the four circles)  in your SVG is this: the rectangle ends in a position which is its width **plus** its `x` (initial) position. The same goes for the vertical scale.

Right now, you have this:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const xMax = 280,
  yMax = 130,
  padding = 20,
  width = 300,
  height = 150;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, xMax])
  .range([padding, width - padding]);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, yMax])
  .range([height - padding, padding]);

svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(0))
  .attr('cy', yScale(0))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('cy', yScale(0))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('cy', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(0))
  .attr('cy', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('rect')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('x', xScale(0))
  .attr('y', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('width', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('height', yScale(yMax));
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

So, why doesn't the rectangle end at the circle on the right-hand side, if that circle is at `xScale(xMax)`? Because you have to subtract the rectangle's `x` position from the width, in order to have this:

```
rectangle's x + rectangle's width = circle's centre
```

And, as previously stated, the same goes for the rectangle's height.

That being said, this is the working demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const xMax = 280,
  yMax = 130,
  padding = 20,
  width = 300,
  height = 150;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, xMax])
  .range([padding, width - padding]);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, yMax])
  .range([height - padding, padding]);

svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(0))
  .attr('cy', yScale(0))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('cy', yScale(0))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(xMax))
  .attr('cy', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', xScale(0))
  .attr('cy', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('r', 10);
svg.append('rect')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('x', xScale(0))
  .attr('y', yScale(yMax))
  .attr('width', xScale(xMax) - xScale(0))
  .attr('height', yScale(0) - yScale(yMax));
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify the issue for others who may have a similar misunderstanding, my issue was mainly with how the scale functions work. I expected `xScale(xMax)` to equal the width of the scaled area, but actually it behaves more like a variable holding a number equal to an svg coordinate, which is greater than the desired width because of the padding. This is more apparent in the inverted Y axis, where `yScale(0)` actually holds a greater number value than `yScale(yMax)` because the scale function references the non-inverted y coordinate. Am I correct?

Comment: Actually, no: `xScale(xMax)` is **exactly** `width - padding`. The problem is that, since the rectangle starts at `padding`, it will end at `padding + width - padding`, which is `width`. Do you see?

Comment: Right, I understand. What I was saying was that I had initially thought the value of `xScale(xMax)` was in the context of the scaled area, but it is actually in the context of the entire svg area.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Yes, but even better is saying that the scale is not in any context! It's just a function that maps a domain to a range. Have a look at my answer here, it has a mathematical explanation of the scale: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539729/5768908